# Descendant selector not working in Internet explorer 9

Tags: html, css

With this markup:

```
    <div id="shopNav">
        <ul>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#">test 1</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>  
    <ul>
        <li class="active1"><a href="#">test</a></li>

    </ul>
```

This doesn't work

```css
#shopnav li.active {
    border:1px solid red !important;    
}
```

but:

```css
.active {border:1px solid red !important;}
```

does work.

I get different behaviours with different doc types:
with

```
<!DOCTYPE PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

The first one is highlighted in FF and not ie8 and with:

The behaviour is consistant, in that only the second li is given the style.

I don't understand this at all as I feel like I've been using this sort of selector for ages... Why doesn't the first selector it work in IE9? And why doesn't the first selector work in either with the loose.dtd ?

See it in action [on this page](http://djembefola.com/shop/test.htm)

Comment: Could you try to present your problem in a more logical way? Your source code on test.htm is just weird!

Comment: Post your code *here*, otherwise if the demo/repro page dies, or moves, the question becomes nonsensical and unhelpful in the future.

Comment: @BjarkeCK I forgot to add the markup, done now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` attribute values are case sensitive. When you have `id="shopNav"`, then in CSS you need to use `#shopNav`, not `#shopnav`.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
#shopnav ul li.active
```

or this

```
#shopnav * li.active
```